# Why am I getting "Future(<not completed>)"

Tags: scala, future

Beginning to learn scala (and futures).

Given the following code:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object MyFuture2 extends App {
  val twenty = Future{Thread.sleep(2000); 20}
  twenty onComplete {
    case Success(nums) => println("twenty onComplete: " + nums)
    case Failure(t) => println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
  }

  while (!twenty.isCompleted ) {
    Thread.sleep(500)
  }
  println("Step 1: " + twenty)

  val myresult = for {
    bb: Int <- twenty
  } yield {
    bb * 2
  }

  println("Step 2: " + myresult)
}
```

The output is

```
twenty onComplete: 20
Step 1: Future(Success(20))
Step 2: Future(<not completed>)
```

"*Step 2: Future()*" does not make sense because almost in the immediate statement earlier, the twenty is already complete, otherwise, it wouldn't print out "Step 1: Future(Success(20))" . The expected value is 40 (20 * 2).

What is wrong with my understanding of how Futures are used? And how can Step 2 ever be not completed!

Thanks.

Comment: There is some overhead in launching a new thread. The scheduler is free to continue the main thread as it sees fit.

Comment: It is not running again, is running the callback. Also, you really should never _"get"_ the result of a `Future` - You should just keep adding transformations and callbacks.

Comment: After modifying as follows `val twenty = Future{println(s"${System.currentTimeMillis()}"); Thread.sleep(2000); 20}`, it seems it's not trigger the tasking again. I'm more confused now. I don't understand what you mean by "is running the callback". And, without using get, how else would you get the result?

Comment: @mbsf You have one `Future` that computes the value `20` then you wait until that one is ready. After that, you register a callback to produce a new `Future` that is equivalent to multiplying by two the result of the first one. Since the first one is already completed the second one can start immediately, but due to the nature of `Futures` that means scheduling a callback in a thread pool which usually takes some time. - That is why using `Futures` for pure CPU bounded tasks is usually a bad idea, unless the amount of work is too big thus that parallelization is worth it.

Comment: since i'm a newbie, I didn't realize the for expression generates a NEW future object!! your explanation makes sense of the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the first part could also have been simply `val twenty = Future.successful(20)` (which executes synchronously on the same thread where you call it) and the result would have been the same (unless for some reason you get lucky with the scheduling).

What is happening is the following:

- you have a `Future` that contains the value `20`
- you call `map` on that (which is the meaning of the `for` comprehension), which sends a callback that multiplies the content of the `Future` by 2 to the global `ExecutionContext` that you imported (which happens to be a fork-join pool)

Now two things can happen:

- most likely, the execution of the current thread continues and you get `Future(<not completed>)` printed
- maybe (but less likely), for some reason the current thread yields and the thread which multiplies by two is scheduled -- the number is multiplied by two and when the control returns to the other thread, `Future(40)` is printed